# Draw vertical lines in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have written following code for generating lines on canvas

**XAML**

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        x:Name="canvas1" Height="219" 
        Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="365"/>
```

**C#**

```
private void Draw()
{
    canvas1.Children.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        data[i] = i;
        lines[i] = new Line()
        {
            X1 = leftMargin,
            Y1 = i * scale,
            X2 = i * scale,
            Y2 = i * scale,
            StrokeThickness = 2,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };
        canvas1.Children.Add(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

[image]

But I want to draw lines as below.How I can rotatle the canvas to achieve the desired output
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't see the images at work, but from the title I understand you want vertical lines, so I'd say that X1 and X2 have to be equal...

Comment: Why don't you just draw vertical lines?

Comment: @Blam:I tried but did not succeeded so that I decided to rotate the canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x = 0 and y = 0 is upper left corner (not lower left) so y is like up side down

```
private void Draw()
{
    Line[] lines = new Line[100];
    int scale = 3;
    canvas1.Children.Clear();
    int yStart = 290;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        //data[i] = i;
        lines[i] = new Line()
        {
            X1 = i * scale,
            Y1 = yStart,
            X2 = i * scale,
            Y2 = 300 - (i * scale),
            StrokeThickness = 1,
            Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)
        };
        canvas1.Children.Add(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="110" CenterY="183" Angle="270" />
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

or by code:

```
Canvas.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(270, 109.5, 182.5);
```

Something like this?

Comment: :I incorporated your code but I am  not getting the expected result

Comment: I have posted the image of desired output

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate the canvas, you can simply apply a transform on it:

```
<Canvas.RenderTransform>
  <RotateTransform CenterX="110" CenterY="183" Angle="270" />
</Canvas.RenderTransform>
```

If you want to do as John Willemse suggested change your code to this :

```
X1 = i * scale,
Y1 = bottomMargin,
X2 = i * scale,
Y2 = i * scale,
```

Comment: I also changed the angle and got the excepted output